# Why if, a/b and b/c, a/c ? b|a . c|b -> c|a

Tags: number-theory

I'm reading An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers
By Godfrey Harold Hardy, G. H. Hardy, E. M. Wright, Roger Heath-Brown, Joseph Silverman.

I've noticed that the transitive property (if a=b and b=c, a=c) is applied. I feel I'm missing something. If you have any suggestions to read something before this or  a piece that focuses on this subject, even extremely in depth, that'd be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean the phenomenon that $3 \mid 6$ and $6 \mid 12$ implies that $3 \mid 12$?

Comment: @Randall Yeah, I feel like I'm getting ahead of myself. I'm trying to focus on the theory rather than numbers, but forgot to use numbers lol. Thanks,I'll work on it

Comment: Is your question why is this true?

Comment: @Randall Yeah, I'm trying to ask how this substitution equates to the transitive property, if it does. It does, right?

Comment: It's the transitive property for the divisibility relation $\,a\mid b\mid c\,\Rightarrow\, a\mid c,\,$ like $\,a < b < c\,\Rightarrow\, a< c\ \ $ $\quad$

Comment: @Randall If a = 1/1,  b = 2/1,  c = 3/1      So,   a/b + b/c implies  a/c     Then  1/1  *  1/2 = 1/2,  2/1  *  1/3  = 2/3,   1/1  *  1/3 = 1/3 ?  Does that help? to show what I'm thinking?

Comment: What does $a= 1/1$ mean?  Do you just mean $a=1$?

Comment: Wait, do you understand that divisibility is a statement and NOT an operation?

Comment: I will point out that only certain relations are transitive while others are not.  Rock beats scissors while scissors beat paper but rock doesn't beat paper.  When given a new relation we investigate what properties it has and we prove that it has those properties.  In this case, we proved that divisibility is transitive, we didn't assume it.

Comment: @Randall I thought division was an operation, like order of operations...? I'd like to know why it's a statement though, um define statement (mathematically, of course) i'm super new

Comment: Oh, this explains a lot.  $a \mid b$ does NOT mean division.  Re-read the book.  $3 \mid 6$ is a true statement, $3 \mid 7$ is not.

Comment: @JMoravitz Great! I'd love a recommendation on that subject or a formal title or something. Thanks! This is very encouraging

Comment: Statements have truth values, they are either true or they are false. "October 25 2018 is a Thursday" is either true or false. "5 is an even number" is a false statement. Statements can have variables in it in which case the truth value depends on the value of the variable, for example "x is larger than 5." In your example the statement "a | b" is a way of writing the statement "b is an integer multiple of a" or equivalently "b divided by a is an integer." For example 6 is a multiple of 2 so "2|6" is a true statement while 2|7 is false. Do not confuse divisibility with division.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you! I think I get it, Use discrete math as a lens for these "abstractions", then layer them based on applicable truths. So helpful

Comment: WOW, thanks everyone! This was a real "Who's on First?" situation and you all really pulled through. MuchLove

Answer (score 1):

This is just a direct application of the definition of divisibility.  If $a \mid b$, this means (by definition) that $b=ak$ for some integer $k$.  If $b \mid c$ this likewise means $c=bm$ for some $m$.  Hence
$$
c=bm=akm
$$
and so $a \mid c$.

I never used transitivity to prove this.  The *claim itself* is that divisibility is transitive.

Comment: So, is this linked by ratio or? Your last statement is reassuring; more than anything I'd love to hear how numbers acquire, keep, etc. "properties". I don't know if my terms are correct.

Comment: Or you said divisibility not numbers lol, but do "operations" have "force"... like a chemistry analogy, are plain numbers in a "stable state"? Thanks!